# Use perl WWW:Mechanize on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: perl, cpan

I want to use WWW:Mechanize with perl on BigSur.
My Perl:

```
    perl 5, version 34, subversion 0 (v5.34.0)
```

I could install perl as far as using the modules:

```
    DBI; 
    LWP::UserAgent; 
    LWP::Simple qw /get/; 
    HTML::TreeBuilder; 
    HTML::Parser;URI qw();
```

Trying to use
 `WWW:: Mechanize;`

fails with:

```
    Can't locate WWW/Mechanize.pm in @INC (you may need to install the WWW::Mechanize module)
```

> ```
> @INC contains: 
> /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level 
> /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0
> /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/lib/perl5/5.34.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level 
> /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/lib/perl5/5.34.0 
> /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0)
> ```

I tryed to load WWW:Mechanize with

> sudo cpanm WWW::Mechanize

with the answer:

> WWW::Mechanize is up to date. (2.03)

But WWW::Mechanize is still not seen by BBEdit.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Seems like you are using Homebrew perl. There might be a conflict with the system perl. How did you install `cpanm` ? What is the output of `which cpanm` ? Did you use `cpanm` to install the other modules also?

Answer (score 2):

Try installing the module with the `cpan` that comes with the homebrew `perl`:

```
% /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/bin/cpan WWW::Mechanize
```

And, to help us with your answer:

- give us the output of `which cpanm` and first line of that file to see the shebang.
- can you load the other modules with the homebrew `perl`? You might have installed them into a different place.

```
#!/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/bin/perl
use DBI; 
use LWP::UserAgent; 
use LWP::Simple qw /get/; 
use HTML::TreeBuilder; 
use HTML::Parser;
use URI qw();
```

Comment: which cpanm: /usr/local/bin/cpanm